# Loop through API till condition is satisfied

Tags: json, powershell, api

Here is code I'm using to get the status, If completed exit and if the status is running loop through untill its get completed status

```
$HOST=https://www.example.com/api/check/status"
$Info=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $HOST -Method GET -Headers $header 

$Status = $Info.last.status
Write-Output $Status

if ($Status -eq "COMPLETED") {

Write-Output "completed"
}
else
{
return $Info
}
```

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help about_Do` or `Get-Help about_While`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, run a Do Until or Do While and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked.Thanks

```
do{
//API call
}unti(//condition)
```